# Recommend a python-twitter API for classroom?

Tags: python, api, twitter, canopy

We're doing an intro-level undergraduate python course and would like to familiarize students with using an API, for example the Twitter API.  I noticed there were many python libraries available to this end, and wanted a recommendation for the library that would fit the following criteria:

1. Easiest to get started with, especially for novices.
2. Best documentation.
3. Preferrably available through Canopy package manager, as the students all are using that environment. (I will crosscheck your recommendations if you don't have access to canopy offhand)

We have about 3 or 4 two hour sessions to devote to this, so we want the most streamlined library for getting started; we don't need it to be fully comprehensive.  I'd also be amenable to other API's if they are supported better than Twitter, but always hear about how easy and powerful Twitter's API really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python-twitter as installed by pip, basically covers most of the twitter API (which you can just use twitters docs. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline to understand and use).

works great for me. not sure if it as a Canopy installer

Comment: Seems like it doesn't have a Canopy installer.  But thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Pure python so just a 1-liner pip install in a Canopy Terminal.

Comment: When you say a canopy terminal, would that work in the ipython shell in canopy?  I'm worried about windows users who don't have cmd windows, and would have to go through the hassle of setting environmental variables and stuff to use a standard terminal.  But they could probably run pip from within canopy's ipython shell, right?